# Eclipse SDK conversion of 3.2 to 4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, sdk

I have product created in eclipse sdk 3.2. i want to upgrade it to eclipse sdk 4.2. As eclipse do not provide downgrade compatibility. I am facing many issues. I have searched for middle layer which can help convert the apis.

If anyone has found solution to similar problem please share

Comment: This is far too broad. Ask specific questions about individual problems you are having. Also Eclipse is now on release 4.6 with significant improvements over 4.2 so you should target 4.6. Finally what has this to do with JBPM?

Comment: yes right this is too broad i could do it till eclipse 3.3 and then i am facing issues. So wanted to know about middle layer. My next target is to achieve 4.6 And my product is also using jbpm.

Comment: Going to 4.2 will just add extra problems as Eclipse 4 was less mature then. Go for Eclipse 4.6 (actually 4.6.1 with 4.6.2 due out before Christmas).

Comment: if i can directly change to eclipse 4.6 that would be great but for that i need middle layer which can help me upgradation with eclipse sdk

Comment: There is no such 'middle layer' code. Properly written Eclipse SDK code should have few problems moving from Eclipse 3.x to 4.x.

Comment: yes Greg, it is having many problem and over net i search for some of them. it is increasing not decreasing.